# Condition for this set of points

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, circles

This is for a calculator experimental prob. simulation. So, there is circle in a square and the circle is touching all 4 sides of the square. We need to first choose a coordinate system (two dimensional). So, it make sense it place the coordinate system at the center of the square. Then calibrate the coordinate system with units. So, let us make the radius of the circle equal to 1 unit. The devise a condition to define all the points in the circle. The condition in the example was $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<=1$ and $x$ was the interval $[-1,1]$ and the $y$ interval was $[-1,1]$. How did they come up with this equation? Lets say we have a square inside a square. Lets say the side of the larger square is 96 and the side of the smaller square is 48. How would you calibrate and where is the origin and what is the conditions that defines that set of points?

Please help, I have a test tomorrow.

Comment: Do you know that the equation for a circle, centered at the origin, with radius 1, is $x^2+y^2=1$?

Comment: yes but why is there a square root

Comment: No good reason. With or without the square root, you get the same values of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: how about the square, do i find each function of each line of the suare

Comment: There's only one way to put a circle in a square. There are lots of ways to put a square in a square, and you haven't picked one.

Comment: It is in the middle of the big square and the figure is in the middle of the bigger square and does not touch any of the bigger squares sides or corners.

Comment: And how is it oriented? (and what is the point of the bigger square, anyway? does it actually affect the answer at all?)

Comment: I don't think we are speaking the same language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of this was to write a program to find the probability of a coordinate falling in the figure out the sample space. So, in the program we can store the sample space on the $x$-axis as an interval called $x$. And we can do the same and make an interval called $y$ for the $y$-axis. Then we can generate a $1000$ trials where the calculator picks a random number from that $x$ and $y$ interval and pairs them together giving us a coordinate. Like this we generate a $1000$ coordinates. Let's say we can define the figure using it boundaries. We can use   each line that makes the figure and find it as a function. Then if we list all the functions and use an inequality to represent not just the lines but also the space inside the figure. So, the calculator checks if the point it generates satisfies the conditions (list of the functions). If a point satisfies the all the inequality-functions then, it is inside the figure. The calculator does this for all the coordinates. It keeps track of the number of coordinates that fell inside of the figure. Then it gives you that number of how many fell inside the figure. Then the calculator displays the number of points that fell inside and it divides it by $1000$ (number of trials) giving you the probability $\left(\frac{\text{number of pairs that fell in the figure}}{1000}\right)$.

So, in this case the condition that represents all the points in the circle and the circle itself is $x^2+y^2<1$ . Then the calculator generates a bunch of points and tests them out and finds out how many fell into the event space and divides it by the number of trials run (number of points tested) giving you the probability. Remember this probability that is generated is just an estimate hence "experimental probability" and not theoretical probability.

Comment: thanks for the help guys!|:)|